# What is difference of MySQL table lock and the row lock of Next-Key Lock?

Tags: mysql, innodb

What is difference of MySQL table lock and the row lock of Next-Key Lock?

In a easy way to say that the table lock will lock the whole table record, and the row lock only lock the single record. But in innodb the row lock have tree alogorithm, the Next-Key Lock will lock the record itself and the record between each record. It seem to me that is no difference to table lock.

Is any difference between two of locks, and after my test the innodb row lock default algotrithm is Next-Key Lock, there is any config can specify the alogrithm of row lock?

Comment: What is a "whole table record"?  "whole table" makes sense; "table record" (aka "table row") makes sense -- that that is just one row of a table.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB rarely does anything like a "table lock".  The main exceptions are related to DDL statements (`ALTER`, `DROP TABLE`, etc)

InnoDB likes to lock individual rows.  It may even lock all the rows in a table, thereby having the effect of a table lock.

It may also do a "gap lock" to prevent other connections from, say, inserting a row with a key between two adjacent existing keys.

Comment: I mean when use the row lock of "Next-Key Lock" that it will lock each record and the range between the each record index value. It seem no difference to me compare to the "table lock". In two those way I can't change the both data either.

Comment: @great-jin - Maybe we need to discuss a specific query.